# ui-router sometimes doesn't change page in Internet explorer > 9

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using ui-router for an application. In IE > 9 the page routing eventually stops working. Especially if I manually change the URL path and hit enter. Sometimes clicking around the application starts it again. This problem does not occur in Chrome, Firefox or IE9. Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, it seems to now be resolved: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/9143

I am now using 1.2.28 and I'm not seeing this problem on IE 11.